# Updating child collection of POCO (adding/updating/deleting) in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4.1

I have a webpage with a form that is used to edit some object. This object contains a Collection of other objects defined like this:

`Public Overridable Property Employees As List(Of Employee)`

On a form I can delete an employee, add a new one or modify existing one. When I click save new values are sent to the server. On a server I check if the user exists. If exists then I modify its values, if it does not exist then I add it. All employees that exist on the server and were not sent are marked as deleted (State changed to EntityState.Deleted). I try to use the following code (dbCollection = database entities, newCollection = collection sent from the form):

```
    For Each item In dbCollection
        Dim dbItem = item
        Dim newTask = newCollection.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.Id = dbItem.Id)


        If newTask Is Nothing Then
            Me.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted
        Else
            Me.Entry(item).CurrentValues.SetValues(newTask)
            newCollection.Remove(newTask)
        End If
    Next

    For Each item In newCollection
        dbCollection.Add(item)
    Next

    Me.SaveChanges()
```

This code does not work, because changing to EntityState.Deleted removes the object from collection, and for each loop breaks, since the collection is modified...

I know that I can overcome this problem by using a for loop or adding objects to delete to some other list first, but I hope maybe there is a pattern that would make my code nicer.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace...

```
For Each item In dbCollection
```

...by:

```
For Each item In dbCollection.ToList()
```

`ToList()` will create a copy of the collection (only the references, not the objects themselves). `dbCollection.ToList()` is another collection than `dbCollection` so that you safely can modify the `dbCollection` without getting the "collection has been modified" exception in the `For Each` loop.

Comment: This is an easy and a feasible solution to my problem. Is it yours or have you seen it somewhere? I will wait a while and see if anyone else posts an answer here. If not I will accept yours.

Comment: @MichalB.: I'm using it myself quite often. You'll see this in many examples, it's kind of a standard solution to solve the "collection has been modified" problem. It's not my invention.